# Understanding Hash Tables with python as a reference

Tags: python, algorithm, hash, hashtable, hash-collision

I am going through online lectures on `data structures` and I want to confirm my understanding of the `hash table`.

I understand that a `hash table` will use a `hashing` function to reduce the universe of all possible keys down to a set `m` and use `chaining` to resolve `collisions`.

I can't seem to visualize the `m` part of it.  Say I create an empty `dict()` in `python`.  Does `python` create a table with some predefined number of empty slots?

Comment: [The Mighty Dict lecture](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=C4Kc8xzcA68) will answer your questions

Comment: [more modern version of the same](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=p33CVV29OG8)

Answer (score 2):

### Overview

An overview of how Python's dictionaries are implemented can be found in the 2017 Pycon talk, [Modern Python Dictionaries A confluence of a dozen great ideas](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=npw4s1QTmPg).

### How to visualize reduction

> I understand that a hash table will use a hashing function to reduce the universe of all possible keys down to a set m and use chaining to resolve collisions. ... I can't seem to visualize the m part of it.

The easiest visualization is with `m == 2` so that hashing divides keys into two groups:

```
>>> from pprint import pprint
>>> def hash(n):
        'Hash a number into evens or odds'
        return n % 2

>>> table = [[], []]
>>> for x in [10, 15, 12, 41, 80, 13, 40, 9]:
        table[hash(x)].append(x)

>>> pprint(table, width=25)
[[10, 12, 80, 40],
 [15, 41, 13, 9]]
```

In the above example, the eight keys all get divided into two groups (the evens and the odds).

The example also works with bigger values of *m* such as `m == 7`:

```
>>> table = [[], [], [], [], [], [], []]
>>> for x in [10, 15, 12, 41, 80, 13, 40, 9]:
        table[x % 7].append(x)

>>> pprint(table, width=25)
[[],
 [15],
 [9],
 [10, 80],
 [],
 [12, 40],
 [41, 13]]
```

As you can see, the above example has two empty slots and slots with a collision.

### Table for an empty dict

> Say I create an empty dict() in python. Does python create a table with some predefined number of null entries?

Yes, Python creates eight slots for an empty table.  In Python's source code, we see `#define PyDict_MINSIZE 8` in [cpython/Objects/dictobject.c](https://github.com/python/cpython/blob/master/Objects/dictobject.c#L111).